# What port is this?

Tags: identification, wire, port

I'm hacking my Honda and there is a female port on one of the circuits that I'd like to extend with a cable (the male port is fixed on the inside of the dashboard). Can anyone identify the port type?

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming the male side is a group of blades?

Comment: It looks like a blade contact to me, as Passerby mentioned. It's probably custom though, so I wouldn't expect you to be able to find a datasheet

Comment: @Passerby, thank you, googling for "blade contact" yielded useful results: http://bit.ly/1NC8Xa5

Comment: @SergeySnegirev measure the pitch between the blades and the width as well to be sure its the right one.

Comment: @Passerby 26 slots are 33mm, Pitch 1.27 mm, width 5mm, so it looks like the exactly right part, `MICS 26`. And `MICA 26` is the receptacle (pictured). Thanks again!